# Custom login module or OAuto provider

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, cloudbees, oauth-provider

I'm writing an application, and I've only had experience using a custom login module with Glassfish fo handling user login.  If deploying in the Cloudbees cloud, I'm assuming that providing a custom login module is not a possibility, correct?  And even if it is, I don't think I really want to use that method.  What mechanisms do you use to secure you application, having user accounts, etc?  If you use an OAuth provider, did you write one yourself?  If so, can you point me to an example so I can do the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John - I have used openid in several places - that seems to work well. I expect a similar solution exists for oauth using servlet filters or similar.

The cloudbees "grandcentral" service is an openid and oauth (I think) provider - for cloudbees accounts.

In theory you should be able to do the same - even if you have to run an embedded glassfish as a zip of jar files with a main launch class.